# Including foreign keys in the View of an entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm going to use pseudo-classes here to illustrate my problem:

```
namespace projectMVC
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Class2 reference { get; set;}
    }

    class Class2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double attribute { get; set;}
    }
}
```

When I set to create the controller and view of `Class1` using the MVC tool it does not include the field for the `Class2` reference. Is there any way to set it to be created or does it have to be a manual process?

PS: The generated controller also doesn't have the necessary code to include the foreign key, although the tables are generates correctly using EF - Code First

Comment: `db.Class1s.Include(o => o.reference)` would include `Class2`. EDIT: include the namespace `using System.Data.Entity` to get this extension method.

Comment: That code goes where?

Comment: In your controller actions generally. `return View(db.Class1s.Include(o => o.reference).ToList())` or `return View(db.Class1s.Include(o => o.reference).SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id = id))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code generators only work on the model class you tell it to use. They don't generate code for related classes as well. The reason why is pretty obvious: you could add editing functionality for those related classes any a number of ways, and it's not Visual Studio's job to determine the needs of your application. For example, you could want inline editing with this model, or you might want a completely separate structure just for that related class.